# Allow only numbers not starting with zero

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I want to allow only numbers which do not start with zero.

I have used the regex `^((?!(0))[0-9]+)$` which worked fine when I tested it with https://www.regextester.com/1926 but in my react app its not working fine.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Here is my code

```
const sharenumberRegex = /^((?!(0))[0-9]+)$/;
estimatedShareValue: Yup.string()
    .matches(sharenumberRegex, "Invalid number")
    .required('*Please type positive number'),
```

Comment: Numbers never start with 0 except decimal numbers below 1  and over -1. Can you provide code ?

Comment: You may be using strings instead of 'numbers'. Please share the code/ reproducible sample to assist further

Comment: _but in my react app its not working fine._ is not helping to understand the issue. can you explain more

Comment: @DominikMatis check edit.

Comment: It's not very clear either, can you provide some examples ?

Comment: can you add the case where it was failing, so i can test it and if you need the explanation of the regex i can add that one

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 /^[1-9]\d*$/
```

[RegExp Reference](https://javascript.info/regexp-anchors)

Comment: what about 1234000?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij would it pass the trailing zeroes number?

Comment: /^[1-9]\d*$/.test("1234000") is true as the caret operators i use matches first characters to be 1 to 9 not others

Comment: just removed the DV.

Comment: _Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?_ This was the actual question.

Comment: Why would `^((?!(0))[0-9]+)$` not work and `^[1-9]\d*$` will?